# read html/text from another html page using jquery

Tags: jquery

is it possible to read or extract html/text from a different .html page using jquery?

this what i would like to read and display in a different page

```
                    <div class="newsItemContent"> 
                      <h1 class="title"> 
                        heading 1
                      </h1>
                      content 1 content 1 content 1 content 1 
                    </div>

                   <div class="newsItemContent"> 
                      <h1 class="title"> 
                        heading 2
                      </h1>
                      content 2 content 2 content 2 content 2 
                    </div>
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Most certainly.  The [$.get() method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/) will do what you want.

Answer (score 4):

You can extract from another page using the [load method](http://api.jquery.com/load/) thus `$('#targetElement').load('page.htm #container')` syntax.

Comment: It causes the page to break all elements (go hidden) and styles to go crazy (page changes color).

Comment: Only if the loaded page is not a fragment. It meets the OPs requirement as specified.

Answer (score 2):

If the page is on the same domain/server you could try to access it through AJAX

Answer (score 1):

If the second page is within an iframe, you could access it with something like:

```
$('#iframeID').contents().html();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yup you can use [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) for this. Or if it's on a different domain JSONP.