# How to use Javascript to access another page's elements?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Say I have a page `a.html` and want to retrieve a text element's text using it's id `<p id="name">NAME</p>` element from another page `b.html`.

Comment: Request the page from an `iframe`, then get the element. But wouldn't you rather just have the server return the data you want?

Comment: possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396542/read-html-text-from-another-html-page-using-jquery

Comment: @kmb385: As long as the second page is on the same domain, it's totally doable.

Comment: Since you didn't ask for jQuery, it should be noted that you do not need to require the user to download and evaluate the entire jQuery library for simple XHR support.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Using jQuery's [`get` method](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), it's pretty simple:

```
$.get('a.html', null, function(text){
    alert($(text).find('#name'));
});
```

Raw XHR Request (*by popular demand*):

```
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

request.addEventListener("load", function(evt){
    console.log(evt);
}, false);

request.open('GET', 'a.html', true),
request.send();
```

Comment: jQuery has no `$.load` method, and it's overkill to load a large library just to do a simple XHR request.

Comment: @user1689607 really?! is it overkill if the client's browser has jQuery already in its cache?

Comment: @Xander: How do you know if it's in the cache?

Comment: @user1689607 — Wrong, [it does](http://api.jquery.com/load/). While it is probably overkill just to make an XHR request, it isn't to make an XHR request, extract data from the resulting HTML document, and add that data to the DOM of the current page.

Comment: @Quentin: OP had `$.load` which *does not work*. And with all due respect, yes it is very simple to do all that.

Comment: works now. `load` would've worked if it was used in the context of match/ed elements. e.g.: `$('p.someparagraph').load( ... );`

Comment: @Xander: Seriously, how do you know? There are at least 3 major CDNs hosting jQuery, all of which host *dozens* of different versions. Not to mention that the browser's cache is finite, and must facilitate many other resources.

Comment: "*Seriously, how do you know?*" there's a high probability that the user has jQuery cached from one of the "*3 major CDNs*." i agree, it is overkill if the only thing you're doing on your page is loading content from another page, but i think there may be more functionality than just "loading content from another page."

Comment: Absolutely, if OP has other uses, then it may be worth the download, but I wouldn't be too quick to assume there's such a high probability of being cached. Again, each CDN hosts dozens of versions. There are plenty of sites that use one of the old (and maybe even one of the unminified) versions. So it's really hit or miss.

Answer (score 2):

You need to:

1. Fetch the content of the page (you imply that [Same Origin Policy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same_origin_policy) won't be a problem, so I won't discuss working around that).
2. Parse that into an HTML DOM
3. Extract the part of that DOM you care about
4. Do something with that DOM

This is quite a lot of work. [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) will do most of the work for you:

```
jQuery('#element_to_load_content_into').load('a.html#name'); // Note use of fragment identifier
```

Comment: @PrathameshDoke — Nothing has fundamentally changed since I wrote this answer.

Comment: This "loads" a webpage partially, I see that a lot of body elements do not exist in the element I loaded the content into. Any idea how to make it load everything?

Comment: @Shayan — I've no idea what you are doing or to what data. Try asking a new question, with an [mcve] and reference this for context.

Answer (score -1):

If the page is on same domain, you can use jQuery.ajax() or jQuery.load()

```
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  data: data,
  success: success,
  dataType: dataType
});
```