# How to change the content of a div on one html page with the contents of a div from another page using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use a link in a TOC (e.g., click me) to replace the current contents of a div on one page with the contents of a div on another page. I'd like to do this just using JavaScript.

Here is the code from the two pages:

Original Page (to receive new content)

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>

<script type= "text/javascript">
    function loadContent(targetPage){
        document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "New text!"; //How do I change this to get the contents of a div in another HTML file?
    }

</script>
</head>

<body>
<div id="link">
    <a href="#"  onClick="loadContent("newContent.html")">Click Me.</a>
    </div>
    <p></p>
<div id="content">
    <p>This is the original content.</p>
</div>


</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Source Page

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Content Source</title>
</head>

<body>

<div id="newContent">
    <p>New Content:</p>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ultricies lacus sed turpis tincidunt id aliquet risus feugiat in. Est velit egestas dui id ornare arcu. Ultricies leo integer malesuada nunc vel. Risus sed vulputate odio ut. Senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas.</p>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I know it's probably not quite what you're looking to do - which is why I'm not writing this as an answer, but have you thought about using jQuery to simply alter the content on your current page? From what I can see, you just want to change your title and the contents of one div (and the id of the div), this is all doable with jQuery, the solution might not scale to bigger pages, but it'll save you faffing with a templating library or trying to grab content from other files with Ajax calls. It is totally possible, but it's like trying to stuff a square peg through a round hole.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use Javascript to access another page's elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899047/how-to-use-javascript-to-access-another-pages-elements)

Comment: Do you need 2 html pages or do you just want the div content to change?

Answer (score 0):

You can use iframe to place one html page inside another.  I changed the inner content of the div to a iframe with the html page as the src.  I also added a style to make the iframe the size of the page.

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
.p2iframe{
width:100%;
height:100%;
float:left;
border:0px;
overflow:hidden;    
}
</style>
<script type= "text/javascript">
function loadContent(){
document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "<iframe class=\"p2iframe\" src=\"page2.html\" name=\"p2iframe\"></iframe>"; 
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="link"><a href="#"  onClick="loadContent();">Click Me.</a></div>
<div id="content"><p>This is the original content.</p></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I don't want to use iframes.  What I'm thinking about is something like this:  document.getElementByID("content).innerHTML = someOtherDocument.getElementByID("newContent).innerHTML 

But in this case, how do I get the "someOtherDocument" part?

Comment: You will need Ajax to pull from 2 pages.  Unless you use iframe, object etc. or another lang like php or Ajax.

Comment: i can give you an Ajax example if it helps.

Comment: Jonny - A complete AJAX example would be great!

Comment: ad another question and let me know.  and i can provide an Ajax answer for you.