# Can't select element on a webpage even though it is present

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to select an element on a table which is on a webpage. The inner text which is on the table is a name of a professor. I am using this line of code to grab the elements.

```js
var tableElementNode = document.querySelectorAll(".section-detail-grid.table-bordered-wrap>tbody>tr>td>div");
```

And yes it works with the tables on the main webpage and grabs the elements I need. However when i try going on a different course page to grab the elements of another table it does not work even though all the tables have the same format. Its as if the tables are invisible to the code and only grabs the ones on the main webpage.

However every so know and then it grabs all the elements I need on a different course page but on very rare occasions.

The last line on the code below is the element I am trying to grab.

```html
<table class="section-detail-grid table-bordered-wrap">
  <thead>
  </thead>
  <tbody>

       <tr data-id="80886" data-index="0" class="section-item section 
        first linked-section">

            <td class="persist row-label">
                          COP
            </td>
            
            <td class=" row-label">
                          3514
            </td>
            
            <td class="persist row-label">
                          001
            </td>
            
            <td class="persist row-label">
                          Class Lecture
            </td>
            
            <td class=" row-label">
                            <div>Wang, Jing</div>
```

Someone mentioned that it may be an ajax driven site and thats why its not grabbing all the elements all the time. Ive even tried getting the xpath of that element but it is still not being found. Why is this element invisible to my code?

Comment: Impossible for us to know without a [mcve] that reproduces the problem. try using a delay before looking for them

Comment: See [Is there a JavaScript/jQuery DOM change listener?](//stackoverflow.com/a/39508954)

Comment: I think what you may be looking for is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12899097/9368476). You can basically access the elements of another page. If this is not what your looking for and I misunderstood the question let me know.

Comment: Both pages are in the same html page