# How to access an element from an external HTML document?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to build a small project where I create a new HTML document (which would be an individual page of an e-commerce product) and another document takes the information from that created document. However, I have no idea how to extract information from an external document without having to embed the entire page with `<iframe>`.

If I use `document.querySelector()` or any other similar function I can get a reference from the elements that have `id` and `class`. However, this function will get the element from the HTML document that is in the JS code I'm working on.

To exemplify my problem let's support that I have `<div id="p1"></div>` inside the `products.html` document to work with the `#p1` element I would have to do this: `let p1 = document.querySelector("#p1")`.

But what if I have an `index.html` document and I want to use the `<div id="p1"></div>` element of `products.html` how would I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can fetch the html file as text, parse it, and run the querySelector

```js
fetch("products.html").then(r=>r.text()).then((html)=>{ // get the content of products.html
  let element = document.createElement("html");
  element.innerHTML = html; // parse the html
  let p1 = element.querySelector("#p1");
});
```

Keep in mind that both documents have to be on the same origin (see: [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS)), so you cannot use this for scraping third party websites

Comment: When I capture `#p1` to add `#p1` inside another element which function would I use?

Comment: Thank you for your help. I managed to increment this function with your code and it worked super well: https://www.horadecodar.com.br/2021/07/24/como-inserir-um-elemento-apos-o-outro-elemento-em-javascript/

Answer (score 1):

use one `js` file and call it in both `products.html` and `index.html`

Comment: So as I said, the JS will be related to the document being used. I want to do in `index.html` something like `products.html#querySelector("#p1")`

Comment: You can see this answers [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12899047/how-to-use-javascript-to-access-another-pages-elements)