# Get element class from another html file

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to get a class name of element from another html file? Or can you do it like this?

```
$(page.html).ready(function(){}
```

The script is rendered in another page.

Comment: Not in a sane way. What are you really trying to do?

Comment: possible duplicate of [read html/text from another html page using jquery](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3396542/read-html-text-from-another-html-page-using-jquery)

Comment: Maybe you can use .load ? $('#content').load('http://whatever #content'); etc

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will work...

```
$.get( "page.html", function( data ) {
    alert($( 'div', data ).attr('class'));
}, "html" );
```

**Edit:**

You can also check `xml` instead of `html` datatype.